# getting variable to display in new method Java

Tags: java, swing, encryption

Im trying to take the input from a user in a textarea in a JFrame and then use it in another class but it keeps coming back null. If i hard code the variable encryptString it will display but not when i save it the Encrypt Action listener

The JFrame encrypt file

```
public class Encrypt extends JFrame {
public String encryptString ;
/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame1
 */
public Encrypt() {
    initComponents();
}


    /**
     * Run on encryption button press
     */
private void encryptionButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    //windowClosed(); 
    run();
encryptString = textForEncryption.getText();

textForEncryption.setText(encryptString +"hey");


    Display display = new Display();
    display.setVisible(true); 

     //close();
}
```

The AES file i am trying to access it in.

```
public class AES {

public static void run(){
    Encrypt e = new Encrypt();
    String strDataToEncrypt =  e.encryptString;
            String strCipherText;
    String strDecryptedText;
            System.out.println(strDataToEncrypt);
            System.out.println(e.encryptString);

    }
```

Comment: Please have a look at http://sscce.org/ to get better answers faster! There is so much irrelevant code here..

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks backwards with your AES method creating an Encrypt GUI and immediately extracting a public (and likely *empty*) String from the GUI before the user has had a chance to  do anything with it. Understand that the GUI that AES is creating is likely not the same one as that being displayed to the user.

No, I think that the GUI, or better its control (its ActionListeners) should have a non-GUI encryption object that gets fed relevant Strings from within the ActionListener's actionPerformed method, and then have the encryption class do its thing.

Something like this, in semi-pseudo-code:

GUI class

```
public class Gui {

  public Gui() {
    myButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(this));
  }
}
```

Control class

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  private Gui gui;

  public ButtonListener(Gui gui)
    this.gui = gui;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String preEncryptString = gui.getPreEncryptString(); // get from text component
    NonGuiEncryption encryption = new NonGuiEncryption(preEncryptString);

    // the code below might need to be done in a background thread 
    // depending on how long it takes to run
    String encryptString = encryption.doEncryption();

    // the code below must be run on the EDT, but after the code above completes
    gui.putEncriptString(encryyptString);
  }  
}
```

Comment: @m4773rz: If you can ask specific questions, maybe I can help.

Comment: so you are saying there is no way i can do it with my current Jframe(encrypt) and AES class? i have to change them?

Comment: @m4773rz: yes, I would change them. But for a more detailed analysis, create and post your [minimal, compiled, example program, or mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @m4773rz: the key question to ask yourself is this: do you understand why your current code is not working? Until you do, you can't use it.